# VB.Net Type conversion

Tags: vb.net, oop

I'm trying to get my head back into VB.Net (been a while) and
can't seem to get around this simple problem.

Here is my abstract base class with its interface:

```
Imports VBRefresh.Animal

Public Interface IAnimal
    ReadOnly Property AnimalType() As TypeOfAnimal
    Property IsAlive As Boolean
End Interface

Public MustInherit Class Animal
    Implements IAnimal

    Public Enum TypeOfAnimal
        Insect
        Mammal
        Fish
        Bird
        Reptile
    End Enum

    Private _animalType As TypeOfAnimal
    Public ReadOnly Property AnimalType As TypeOfAnimal Implements IAnimal.AnimalType
        Get
            Return _animalType
        End Get
    End Property

    Private _isAlive As Boolean
    Public Property IsAlive() As Boolean Implements IAnimal.IsAlive
        Get
            Return _isAlive
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            _isAlive = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(animalType As TypeOfAnimal)
        _animalType = animalType
    End Sub

End Class
```

And here are two derived classes (of which `Cow` is extending `IAnimal`):

```
Public Interface ICow
    Inherits IAnimal

    Property FriendlyName As String
End Interface

Public Class Cow
    Inherits Animal
    Implements ICow

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New(TypeOfAnimal.Mammal)
    End Sub

    Private _friendlyName As String
    Public Property FriendlyName As String Implements ICow.FriendlyName
        Get
            Return _friendlyName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _friendlyName = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

Public Class Eagle
    Inherits Animal

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New(TypeOfAnimal.Bird)
    End Sub

End Class
```

I'm trying to change type of `myAnimal` to a `Cow` so I can access it's property `FriendlyName` but I can't get it to work without

1. Creating a seperate object and setting that.
2. Declaring `FriendlyName` in the `IAnimal` interface..
   I tried casting `myAnimal` to `ICow` but that doesn't give me access to the `FriendlyName` property?

   ```
   Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

     Dim myAnimal As IAnimal = New Eagle
     myAnimal.IsAlive = True

     myAnimal = New Cow
     myAnimal.FriendlyName = "Bella" 'this line doesn't work

     Dim myCow As ICow = New Cow
     myCow.FriendlyName = "Bella"

     MessageBox.Show(myAnimal.AnimalType.ToString)
   End Sub
   ```

Probably something stupid but I'm running out of options here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared `myAnimal as IAnimal`. IAnimal doesn't have the Property `FriendlyName`.

Therefore you have to cast `IAnimal` to `Cow`:

`DirectCast(myAnimal, Cow).FriendlyName = "Bella"`

OR

`DirectCast(myAnimal, ICow).FriendlyName = "Bella"`

Comment: Thanks, I knew this already but I need an object ICow from myAnimal.

Answer (score 0):

If I would like to use the newly cast object as an object itself,
I need to create an object of type ICow to which I assign the casted object:

```
Public Class Main
    Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim myAnimal As IAnimal = New Eagle
        myAnimal.IsAlive = True

        myAnimal = New Cow
        myAnimal.FriendlyName = "Bella" 'this line doesn't work

        myAnimal = DirectCast(myAnimal, ICow)
        myAnimal.FirendlyName = "Bella" 'this is still unavailble?

        'guess I have to solve it this way then:
        Dim myCow As ICow = DirectCast(myAnimal, ICow)
        myCow.FriendlyName = "Bella"

        MessageBox.Show(myAnimal.AnimalType.ToString)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Each time you use the object `myAnimal`, you have to cast it because IT IS declared as IAnimal. You have to tell the compiler what specific type you await.

Comment: The above does not compile, I'm getting that the cast is invalid from Eagle to ICow. So how can I create an object that has the same base class and implements the same base interface? Convert myAnimal to an ICow object type?